# Pascal's triangle in asm 8086

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086, pascals-triangle

I tried to make a program that will calculate Pascal's triangle,
however my program is incorrect.

```
org 100h

; Set an array with size equal to 100
array db 1, 99 dup(0)

_start: 
    
    mov si, 1 ;repreasent if we add already 100 values and we should stop the loop 
    mov di, 1 ;di set to be the row
    mov bp, 0; bp set to be the index  
    
    mov [array + di * 10 ], 1
    mov [array + di * 10 + 1], 1
    inc si
    inc si
    inc di ;we start from row number 2
    
 
    ;lets move to a new row 
     
    jmp move_to_new_row
      
    ;after the move to the enew row is finish we go the full array and we want to print it out 
    mov ax, 0
    jmp move_over_array
    

;this lable make sure to load values to array 
add_values_to_row:
    
    mov al, [array + <(di - 1) * 10> + bp]
    mov dl, [array + <(di -1) * 10 > + bp -1]
    add al, dl ; add the arr[line - 1][i] + arr[line- 1][i-1]
    
    mov [array + bp], al; set the index to the sum of indedxes in the privios line 
    inc si ; adding to the numbers of adding values 1
    ;update the values 
    inc bp;adding 1 to the index
     
    
     

move_to_new_row:
    mov [array + di], 1 ;set the first index of the new row to be 1 
    mov bp, 1 ; we starting full the row from index = 1
    mov cx, 10 ; move the loop 10 times 
    loop add_values_to_row ;full the new row 
    ;now we full a row good lack lets go to the new row 
    inc di; adding 1 to the row
    cmp si, 100 ;checking if we adding to the array all the 10 lines 
    JB move_to_new_row ; add another line for full 

    
print_new_line:
    mov bl , 0
    PRINTN " "
         
 
print_using_ax:
    mov bx, ax           ; Move the value from al to bx
    mov al, [array + bx] ; Use bx as an index
    call print_num
    inc ax               ; Increment the index (assuming 16-bit elements, adjust accordingly)
    inc bl
    cmp bl, 10
    JE print_new_line
    
move_over_array:
    mov bl, 0
    ;move over the array and print the value using ax register 
    loop print_using_ax
    int 16h
    ret 

; Include magshimim library used for print and so on 
include magshimim.inc
```

Comment: Are you sure that execution begins at *_start*? Don't you need a jump over the 100-byte array? `org 100h` `jmp _start` `array db 1, 99 dup(0)`

Comment: All of those scaled addressing modes are invalid for the 8086 code that you aim for.  `mov [array + di * 10 ], 1` is wrong. Once you start using x86 assembly then you could use scaled addressing but even then the only allowable factors are 1, 2, 4, and 8. Never 10 or anything else!

Comment: @SepRoland Technically, 386 scaled addressing can encode some other choices such as times 3, times 5, or times 9, by encoding eg `[edi + edi * 8]`. However, times 10 is not among those.